# UIComboBox... Where is it?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

So I'm pretty sure i already know the answer to this, but does the SDK include access to the combo box control used in mobile safari?

It should be easy enough to build one... but I'm not looking to re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not built in, no.  Even as they have its just a text field and a UITable working together.

Comment: I suspected as much.  Thanks.

Comment: You can also try using the Picker.